# Excel Conditional Formatting Multiple Rules Changing Blank Cells After Data Entry

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, nonblank

I have a row with a dropdown list (Yes/No) that turns 3 columns yellow indicating to the user that they need to enter data into the cells. This works well with the formula (=$A3="Yes").

[image: CF1 Example]

My spreadsheet has a second condition to format blank cells needing data as yellow which goes away with data entry. For Input 1, 2, and 3, I need another CF rule to remove the yellow after data entry. Using the Format Cells that Contain Blanks does not work as shown here.

[image: CF2 Example]

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input 1 condition: =AND($Q# = "Yes", $R# = "") Apply Cell Input 1. Don't $ front of cell # and then you can copy and paste. You have alternate coloring, do individually on first light & dark cells then you can drag down.

Input 2 condition, do the same thing, =AND($Q# = "Yes", $S# = "").

I sent J the file :)